# Assign slides by class in SlickSlider

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am trying to assign slides by class to SlickSlider via options in JSON format.

Option "slide":".plan-item" brakes JSON. Any suggestions?

```html
<div class="plans-slider js__slick" data-slick-options='{"slide":".plan-item","dots":true,"arrows":true,"autoplay":false,"infinite":false,"autoplaySpeed":5000, "focusOnSelect": false, "focusOnChange": false, "accessibility": false, "slidesToScroll":3, "slidesToShow":3}'>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="editor" id="editslides">edit slides</div>
      <div class="editor" id="reorder">re-order slides</div>
       <div class="myslides">
         <div class="plan-item">PLAN-1</div>
         <div class="plan-item">PLAN-2</div>
         <div class="plan-item">PLAN-3</div>
         <div class="plan-item">PLAN-4</div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include all relevant code, ie. the JS. Also, what do you mean by it 'breaks JSON' - that makes no sense.